# Hibernate listener executed in separate transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

In our application we have a `PostDeleteEventListener` registered that is executed for each deleted owning entity and possibly for related entities (if cascading delete is enabled).
The listener is used to inspect each entity for a certain property that represents the ID of an entity that is located in one big centralised table without foreign key relation.
The discovered ID's are stored in a `java.util.Set` held by a `ThreadLocal`.

What we're looking for is some 'transaction hook' to trigger one delete statement (for performance reasons) with all the ID's held by the `java.util.Set`.

We tried to achieve this by using a Spring aspect that is executed after a `@Transactional` method has run. The aspect could then fire the delete statement and clear the java.util.Set.
Unfortunately, it seems that the `PostDeleteEventListener` is executed AFTER the aspect is triggered. In other words, it gets executed in a separate transaction which I can clearly see by inspecting the stacktrace while debugging. So having an aspect for this doesn't look the way to go...

An other option seems to have a second listener (`FlushEventListener`) that is executed when the session is flushed.
Although this works, we don't know if this is a good solution?

Are there any other (and better) alternatives out there we can use for this issue?
Is there an other way (Spring or Hibernate) to get notified just before the transaction is committed?

Comment: database triggers are out of the question?

Comment: We try to manage this by Hibernate as we're also planning to detect changes when doing a merge/saveOrUpdate

Comment: does [this](http://riteshadval.blogspot.co.nz/2010/08/spring-using-hibernate-interceptor.html) help?

Comment: We ended up to refactor everything into a Hibernate Interceptor. We store the label ID's into a Set contained by a ThreadLocal. This Threadlocal is read out in the 'beforeTransactionCompletion' method to ensure everything is committed in the same transaction.

Comment: you should make than an answer.